# Take the last portion of the string by indexing

Tags: r, string, indexing

I have to split a string by the delimiter "-", and take out the part on the far right.

```
SKU <- c("PPM-UA-L", "RVK-JI-XL", "KMN-WO-XS", "YYL-S")
```

However, in below codes, [ ,3] will not work for all cases, as some of them have only one "-". In below example, the last value "YYL-S" will return nothing.

```
size <- str_split(SKU, "-", simplify = T)[ ,3]
```

I also tried this to do backward indexing, but got error message. Also tried [ , -1], but negative index number in R does not indicate counting backwards.

```
size <- str_split(SKU, "-", simplify = T)(rev[ ,3])
```

Comment: What is your expected output - `"L"  "XL" "XS" "S"`? If so, `gsub("^.+-", "", SKU)`

Comment: You can use `tail()` to get the last element of input, e.g. `SKU |> strsplit("-") |> sapply(tail, 1)`. Or `head(x, -1)` to remove the last element, `strsplit(SKU, "-") |>  lapply(head, -1) |> sapply(paste, collapse = "-")`... not really sure which you're going for.

Comment: @SamR Yes, that is the result that I wanted. Thanks! What is "gsub" and what library does this require?

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks much! What does this sign do "|>"?

Comment: It's a pipe, `x |> foo() |> bar()` is equivalent to `bar(foo(x))`.

Comment: `sub()` and `gsub()` are both base R functions - no libraries required.

Answer (score 4):

### Vectorised string operations are faster than creating and destroying objects in memory (see benchmarks below)

Solutions which create lists of vectors that you do not need tend to be relatively slow. You can use regular expressions here to replace everything up to and including the final `-`.

```r
sub(pattern = "^.+-", replacement = "", SKU)
# [1] "L"  "XL" "XS" "S"
```

The caret (`^`) is a regex [metacharacter](https://www.gastonsanchez.com/r4strings/metacharacters.html) which matches the beginning of the string. The matches any character except a new line. The `+` means "match the preceding character one or more times". The `.+` combination is [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions), meaning it will find the longest match from the start to the end of the string. All together this means, match from the beginning of the string until and including the final `-`.

The [`sub()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/grep) function replaces the first occurrence of the `pattern` in `x` (which in this case is `SKU`) with the `replacement` (which in this case is a blank string).

You can read more [here](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Internet/NEWS/regexp.html#basics) about the syntax used in regular expressions.

### Benchmarking

I benchmarked five approaches:

1. Base R `sub()`.
2. Base R `strsplit() |> sapply()`.
3. Base R `strsplit() |> vapply()`.
4. `stringr::str_split_i()`.
5. `stringr::str_split() |> vapply(\(x) tail(x, 1), character(1))`.
6. base R lookbehind: `regmatches(gregexpr()`.
7. `stringr::str_extract()` lookbehind.

I repeated the vector from `10` to `1e5` times. `sub()` is consistently the fastest approach with the least garbage collection (`gc`), i.e. fewest memory allocations.

There is not much difference between `base::strsplit()` and `stringr::str_split()`. `sapply` does not appear different to `vapply()`. `stringr::str_split_i()` is faster than the other approaches which split the vector, and has less garbage collection, but is not as fast as `sub()`.

`stringr::str_extract()` with a lookbehind is almost as fast as `sub()`. Using the same pattern in base R with `regmatches(gregexpr())` is much slower (presumably because it returns a list).

[image]

### Code to generate the plot

```r
results <- bench::press(
    rep_num = rep_nums,
    {
        x <- rep(SKU, rep_num)
        bench::mark(
            min_iterations = 10,
            sub = {
                sub("^.+-", "", x)
            },
            strsplit_base_sapply = {
                strsplit(x, "-") |>
                    sapply(tail, 1)
            },
            strsplit_base_vapply = {
                strsplit(x, "-") |>
                    vapply(\(x) tail(x, 1), character(1))
            },
            str_split_i = {
                str_split_i(x, "-", -1)
            },
            str_split_vapply = {
                str_split(x, "-") |>
                    vapply(\(x) tail(x, 1), character(1))
            },
            base_r_lookbehind = {
                regmatches(
                    x,
                    gregexpr("(?<=-)[^-]+$", x, perl = TRUE)
                ) |> unlist()
            },
            stringr_lookbehind = {
                str_extract(x, "(?<=-)[^-]+$")
            }
        )
    }
)


library(ggplot2)
autoplot(results) +
    theme_bw() +
    facet_wrap(vars(rep_num), scales = "free_x")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str_split_i` with `i = -1` to get the last part:

```r
library(stringr) #1.5.0
str_split_i(SKU, "-", -1)
# [1] "L"  "XL" "XS" "S"
```

Comment: I am not familiar with this function. What package is it from?

Comment: It's stringr, latest version

Comment: I can't run this function, str_split_i. How do I get the latest version of STRINGR library? Thanks!

Comment: You can update the packages, (google it) or use `install.packages("stringr")` again

Comment: @Maël Thanks. I tried that by installing stringr again, but it ended up messing up my other libraries :-( Now I can't get my dplyr or ggplot2 to work, and still str_split_i does not work either. How do I fix these issues? I apologize for this.

Comment: It usually involves updating other packages as well. I'd suggest to update everything, especially since `dplyr` has released several useful function in the last weeks

Comment: @Maël thanks - clearly didn't have the latest version. Just tried it out - seems faster than `str_split()` but slower than `sub()`.

Comment: @Maël By "update everything", does that mean I have to re-install all other packages? Thanks.

Comment: @Maël I just re-installed stringr, but that function str_split_i is still not woking.

Comment: Probably, yes. Packages usually relies on other packages, and if those are not updated, then you can't update the others. Check if your `stringr` version is 1.5.0

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `str_extract` with lookbehind `(?<=-)`, a negative character class disallowing the `-` character and, finally, the last-position anchor `$`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(SKU, "(?<=-)[^-]+$")
[1] "L"  "XL" "XS" "S"
```

To simplify (and perhaps to speed up) things, we can drop the look-behind entirely and rely solely on the negative chracter class in combination with the string-end anchor `$`:

```
str_extract(SKU, "[^-]+$")
[1] "L"  "XL" "XS" "S"
```

Here then, `str_extract` extracts that substring that does not include a `-` and that ends when the whole string ends

Comment: Nice - I added this to the benchmark in my answer. Interestingly (to me at least) this is a lot faster than the only way I could think of to do an equivalent thing in base R, `regmatches(SKU, gregexpr("(?<=-)[^-]+$", SKU, perl = TRUE)) |> unlist()`. It is still not quite as fast as `sub()`, although these timings are more for my own interest than because it's important to optimise operations such as these for speed.

Comment: Thanks! What part in your code represents the delimiter "-" (dash)? Thanks again.

Comment: The delimiter is included in the positive look-behind `(?<=-)`, which impements an instruction to match only if the *preceding* character is `-`

Comment: @SamR ah, that old regmatches-cum-gregexpr combo - not surprising the `str_extract` solution from the `stringr` package is faster than that long-winded `base R` method. `stringr`, a package for all things regex which is part of the `tidyverse`, is wildly superior to any `base R`regex functions - check it out!